# ORA-12514 error after rebooting

Tags: oracle-11g

We have an **oracle 11g** cloud database that was working fine until recently when it started throwing the ORA-12514 after every reboot. The instance is programmed to be started up every morning and shutdown two hours later.

To be able to fix this, I have to do the following every morning because it gets reinitialized after rebooting:

```
1) sudo su oracle
2) sqlplus /nolog
3) connect sys/xxxxxx as sysdba
4) shutdown abort;
5) startup
6) alter system set local_listener ='(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxxxx.subnet.vcn.oraclevcn.com)(PORT=1521))' SCOPE=BOTH;
7) alter system register
8) quit
```

I have tried many things. First of all, I have tried **tnsping** the database and it works fine, so the listener is reachable.

I have seen in many other posts that we need to have the same service name in the database, in the **listener.ora** and **tnsnames.ora** files to fix this error, so I made sure of that.

Here are the **tnsnames.ora** file:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DB2020 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxx.subnet.vcn.oraclevcn.com)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = DB2020_lhr1vc.subnet.vcn.oraclevcn.com)
    )
  )
```

and the **listener.ora** file:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxx.subnet.vcn.oraclevcn.com)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

So it works fine when you add it back in manually, but not when it starts itself?
Sounds like the "LOCAL_LISTENER" Initialization Parameter in the database itself has been lost.

Not sure why you're using a non-standard Listener anyway, but then you're running an unsupported version anyway.  Not sure which will give you more trouble.
You should seriously consider upgrading.